# Backtrace for GNU make

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

Is there any way to get GNU make to print a "backtrace" of the targets that led to the command being executed when it fails? I regularly deal with heavily obfuscated makefiles while resolving portability issues building software on a new system, and it seems like this should be an extremely simple thing for make to do that would greatly aid in debugging, but I can't find any way to request it. What I'd like to see is something like:

```
gcc: error: ...
make[2]: error: gcc ...
make[2]: error building target bar
make[2]: error building dependency bar for target foo
make[1]: error: make -C subdir
make[1]: error building target subdir
make[1]: error building dependency subdir for target all
...
```

showing the entire dependency path for how the failed command ended up getting executed.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: For what it's worth, the "backtrace" might not be linear, because in general make's dependency graph is a DAG, not a tree. It could be making `bar` for target `foo` *and* target `subdir`, and it could be making target `foo` for target `subdir` and target `all`, and making `subdir` for `all`. I don't think this makes it any harder to generate than a stack backtrace, just harder to read...

Comment: If you think of this as a dependency try, yes, it is a DAG. However in GNU Make's traversal, there is strictly a dependency stack.  So while "backtrace" generally refers to a call stack, here the analogous thing is a dependency stack.

Answer (score 4):

Use [**remake**](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/). It is a patched version of GNU Make that adds improved error reporting, the ability to trace execution in a comprehensible way, and a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

`make -p` and `make -d` provide interesting information, but not precisely what you are asking for. See [make's man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary).

Comment: The OP might also find `make -n` helpful.

Comment: Yep, these are your friends. If your makefiles don't use any of the built-in make rules, you can reduce the verbosity of the output with `-Rr` (you only need one of these but I can never remember which, so I always use both).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [remake](http://github.com/rocky/remake) can give you a backtrace. Here is a run to using the remake's Makefile show this:

```
    remake --debugger Makefile
    GNU Make 4.1+dbg0.91
    Built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    Copyright (C) 2015 Rocky Bernstein.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
    Reading makefiles...
    Updating makefiles....
    -> (/src/github/remake/Makefile:608)
    Makefile: Makefile.in config.status
    remake<0> bt
    =>#0  Makefile at /src/github/remake/Makefile:608
    remake<1> s
    -> (/src/github/remake/Makefile:594)
    Makefile.in: 
    remake<2> bt
    =>#0  Makefile.in at /src/github/remake/Makefile:594
      #1  Makefile at /src/github/remake/Makefile:608
    remake<3> s
    -> (/src/github/remake/Makefile:618)
    config.status: configure
    remake<4> bt
    =>#0  config.status at /src/github/remake/Makefile:618
      #1  Makefile at /src/github/remake/Makefile:608
    remake<5> s
    -> (/src/github/remake/Makefile:621)
    configure: 
    remake<6> bt
    =<#0  configure at /src/github/remake/Makefile:621
      #1  config.status at /src/github/remake/Makefile:618
      #2  Makefile at /src/github/remake/Makefile:608
    remake<7>
```

You could also set a breakpoint at a particular target (`break`), go there (`continue`) and `backtrace` that. And on error, you will get a backtrace of where you were at when you crashed.